# How to add two torch tensors along given dimension?

Tags: python, torch, broadcasting

I have a torch tensor, `pred`, in the form (B, 2, H, W) and I want to sum two different values, `val1` and `val2`, to the channels on axis 1.

I managed to do it in a "mechanical" way by accessing the single channels directly, e.g.:

```
def thresh_format(pred, val1, val2):
    tr = torch.zeros_like(pred)
    tr[:, 0, :, :] = tr[:, 0, :, :].add(val1)
    tr[:, 1, :, :] = tr[:, 1, :, :].add(val2)
    return pred + tr
```

However I'm wondering if there's a "better" way to do it, e.g. by exploiting broadcasting. My understanding from the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics) is that broadcasting happens from trailing dimensions, so in this case I'm puzzled how to make it work for dimension 1.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to stack val1 and val2 in a tensor and reshape it to match the shape of the pred tensor along the common dimension.

```
 pred + torch.tensor([val1, val2]).reshape((1,-1,1,1))
```

This way, for the addition, torch automatically broadcasts the values along the dimensions where pred has higher order.

It's pretty similar to what happens when you just add a simple scalar value to a tensor, like:

```
>>> torch.ones((2, 2)) + 3.
tensor([[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]])
```

But instead of broadcasting the one scalar value to every element of the tensor during the addition, in the aforementioned case the values are broadcasted along the dimensions that do not already match.

```
>>> B=1; W=2; H=2; val1=3; val2=7
>>> pred = torch.zeros((B,2,W,H))
>>> val = torch.tensor([val1, val2]).reshape((1,-1,1,1))
>>> pred
tensor([[[[0., 0.],
          [0., 0.]],

         [[0., 0.],
          [0., 0.]]]])
>>> val
tensor([[[[3]],

         [[7]]]])
>>> pred + val
tensor([[[[3., 3.],
          [3., 3.]],

         [[7., 7.],
          [7., 7.]]]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) can you comment on what is the `-1` doing in `.reshape`?

Comment: yeah, it achieves the same thing as if you would write (1,2,1,1) but it essentially tells torch to figure out the correct dimension itself. 
You have two values in the original tensor -> they both need to go somewhere during the reshape -> "-1" in the second dimension says: use this dimension for the values.

Quoting reshape docs: "A single dimension may be -1, in which case it’s inferred from the remaining dimensions and the number of elements in input."
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#torch.reshape

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! :D I'll leave it open for a while just to see if something else interesting comes up (I'm always surprised by how much I can learn from other users strategies than I could have never thought of) :)